# SQL Server : Select from two tables with default value 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, default-value

Table - BASECASE(CaseNumber, PatientID)

```
CaseNumber------PatientID
S100---------------P201
S101---------------P201
S102---------------P200
S103---------------P199
S104---------------P201
```

2nd table

```
Table - CHECKUP(CheckupNumber, CaseNumber)
CheckupNumber------CaseNumber
C301-------------------S100
C302-------------------S100
C303-------------------S101
C304-------------------S102
C305-------------------S103
```

SQL Code

```
SELECT CaseNumber FROM BASECASE
 & COUNT(CaseNumber)FROM CHECKUP, WHERE PatientID='P201'
```

If the CaseNumber is Not present in CHECKUP, COUNT(CaseNumber)[which will be null] should return value 0.

Expected result.

```
CaseNumber-----No.Of Checkups
S100------------------2
S101------------------1
S104------------------0
```

How to sort out this problem?

Comment: Hint: Searhc for Left join, count function, group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `left join` and `group by`

```
select B.caseNumber, ISNULL(count(C.checkupNumber) ,0)
from BaseTable B
left join Checkup C
on B.caseNumber = C.caseNumber
where B.patientId ='P201'
group by B.caseNumber
```

Comment: IF Count(B.CaseNumber)=Null, It should return 0!

Answer (score 1):

**Join with Group BY**

```
select BC.Casenumber,isnull(COUNT(BC.Casenumber),0) CNT from BaseCase BC
left
join CheckUp Ch
on BC.CasetNumber=Ch.CaseNumber
group by BC.Casenumber
```

Comment: IF Count(BC.CaseNumber)=Null, It should return 0!

Comment: @SHREE now updated you can just use `isNULL` function

Comment: SELECT B.CaseNumber, ISNULL(COUNT(B.CaseNumber),0) CaseCount FROM BASECASE B JOIN CHECKUP C ON B.CaseNumber=C.CaseNumber WHERE B.PatientID LIKE 'P201' GROUP BY B.CaseNumber

Comment: the above query is not returning Null as 0.

Comment: Should use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use Left Join with Group by**

SELECT cn.cno,Count(cp.cno) as NoofCheckup FROM casenumber cn LEFT JOIN checkup cp ON cn.cno=cp.cno
                     WHERE cn.patientid='P201'
                     GROUP BY cn.cno